# Script to redirect user to authors site if he removes code

Tags: javascript, redirect, hyperlink

Suppose there is a site abc which uses code made by the author of xyz. I want a JavaScript so that whenever abc removes the footer links he would be redirected to xyz's site. It is possible as I have seen it in 2-3 sites but the code is encrypted so that is of no use for me. Please help me.

Comment: That is the point. If not obfuscated, the code to redirect would just be removed

Comment: Because Javascript runs on the client's computer and has no compilation stage (= the source code is visible to the client), it is impossible to guarantee that your javascript will run on your client at all, or in the same way as you intend it to (they can edit it, use a debugger...).

Comment: @Patashu well it has a compilation stage on the client :P ... and you also could say even compilation is just obfuscation (the instruction that do something are still there but just harder to read). But yes js obfuscation is just a protection against _copy'n'past coders_ :D

Comment: @t.niese Yeah, I meant to compare it to languages like C/C++, where you must use a decompiler or study the assembly yourself, and in general you don't have the source code the programmer did, whereas in javascript the source code is 'plainly there'.

Comment: @Patashu should not be offensive :) and about the source code. with google _closure compiler_ in advanced mode, i sometimes get really scary in what the _compiler_ is doing to my code. I always hope that my code is still running, because the output sometimes has nearly nothing to do with my input ^^ But yes it is still readable and copy protections can be removed without problems, even if it is fully refactored by google :D

Comment: @t.niese Oooh, the closure compiler is cool

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say the footer links look like this

```
<div id="xyz-links">
  <a href="http://xyz.com">Author xyz.com</a>
</div>
```

This should work for you!

```
// xyz links removed!
if ($("#xyz-links").length == 0) {
  window.location = "http://xyz.com";
}
```

Here's a compressed ultra l33t vers10n

```
0==$("#xyz-links").length&&(window.location="http://xyz.com");
```

That said, this could be easily reverse engineered by anyone with brain larger than a peanut.

Don't worry about not getting mad props or street cred for your ultra sweet codez! Leeches are gonna leech. Just keep writing good code and keep your head up, bru.